# React checkboxes "Cannot read property" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am trying checkboxes (component) in react and trying to get all the variables checked. I wrote the code as:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    Card,
    Container,
    CardBody,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    Button,


} from "reactstrap";

export default class Chk extends React.Component {

    states={
        Colornames:{
            ship:false,
            cabin:false,
            grade:false,
            rate:false,
            marketing:false,
            image:false
        }
    }

    chkClick = (e) => {
        var {name, checked} = e.target;
        var name = e.target.name;
        var checked = e.target.checked;
        console.log("xxxxx", e.Colornames)
        this.setState((e) => {
            var SelectedSport = e.Colornames;
            return SelectedSport[name]=checked;
        });
    };


    render() {
        var displaySports = Object.keys(this.states.Colornames);
        console.log("aaaaaa", displaySports)
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ship" onChange={this.chkClick}/> Ship&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cabin" onChange={this.chkClick}/> Cabin&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="grade" onChange={this.chkClick}/> Grade&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rate" onChange={this.chkClick}/> Rate&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="marketing" onChange={this.chkClick}/> Marketing&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="image" onChange={this.chkClick}/> Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is giving error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Colornames' of null

i feel its all fine with the code.
Finally i need all the checkboxes value (checked: true/false) so that i can do a search from the data as per the checkboxes checked
BTW i am using a mac machine with chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went through the problem statement again, and found out that the state initialisation wasn't correct. While using the React Class Components, the state should be initialised inside the constructor. I have tried to make the function `chkClick` a little simpler and everything is working as per exepctation.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            colornames: {
                ship: false,
                cabin: false,
                grade: false,
                rate: false,
                marketing: false,
                image: false
            }
        }
    }

    chkClick = (e) => {
        var { name, checked } = e.target;
        console.log(name, checked);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                colornames: {
                    ...prevState.colornames,
                    [name]: checked
                }
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ship" onChange={this.chkClick} /> Ship&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cabin" onChange={this.chkClick} /> Cabin&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="grade" onChange={this.chkClick} /> Grade&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rate" onChange={this.chkClick} /> Rate&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="marketing" onChange={this.chkClick} /> Marketing&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="image" onChange={this.chkClick} /> Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It is state not states by the way

Comment: The variable is fine. its just somehow **SelectedSport[name]=checked;** this should store all the checked values.

Comment: Thanks @jateen this really helps. is there a way to extract the true values and export that to another jsx file?

Comment: @jateen the requirement i have is that, i have a datatable and i want to search data in one of the column based on the checkboxes checked. the check boxes will have unique values of the column (there are only 5 unique values).
is there a direct and quick solution to this?